# 502 bad gateway when accessing Kube load balancer IP on browser

Tags: flask, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes deployment running on a load balancer with a external IP created to access it outside my virtual machine. The deployment points to a docker image of a flask app which runs perfectly fine on its own.

However when copy-pasting the external IP of the loadbalancer I obtain the following error:

```
502 Bad Gateway, the destination was unreachable
```

Here is my deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: flask-test
spec:
  selector:
   matchLabels:
    app: flask-test
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flask-test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flask-test
        image: <image uri>
        ports:
         - containerPort: 5000
```

Here is my loadbalancer file:

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Service
 metadata:
  labels:
   app: flask-lb
  name: flask-lb
 spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: flask-lb
   port: 5000
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 5000
  selector:
   app: flask-test
```

I have checked the description of both deployment and service and the ports match, the pods are running and the service is healthy. What could be the reason for a 502 bad gateway?

There are no other services running on port 5000

Comment: are you trying to send the request to the right port? i mean if your service typed load balancer there got to be a node port that from it he waits for traffic, and you need to send your request to that port

Comment: Could you explain how exactly did you set up your cluster and deployments? What did you use (which versions?) It is important to reproduce your problem.